# How to put dropzone within a form but still allow the original form to submit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone

I have a form, and I want to put a dropzone into it.

I don't want to submit the images along with the main form, as I will store their details in the Session, and then store the filenames and other details in the DB when the form is submitted.

However, putting the dropbox in the form stops the submit button from working.

I'm creating the dropzone in a div ina Vue component:

```
<div :id='"dropzoneform" + this._uid' class="dropzone">
```

And then instantiating it programatically:

```
var form = this.$el;
this.dropzone = new Dropzone(form, {
  url: this.postUrl,
  headers: this.headers,
  // ...more settings...
}
```

Auto-detect is false too:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

The dropzone works, and it uploads the files as intended. But I cannot submit the form that they are in. I click the button but nothing happens.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

edit: here's the button code:

```
<button type="submit" class="booking-submit" name="button" @click.prevent="submit">Continue</button>
```

and the submit function has a load of stuff to check the form has been filled in properly, and ends with an:

```
if (submittable) {
  $('#form').submit();
}
```

I've put a console.log in this if to confirm it's getting there, and it is. Also this form worked before I put the dropzone in.

Comment: Do you have the code for your button and click method?

Comment: I also would like to see the complete html form.

Comment: @varborb thank you I have edited the answer

Comment: Where's your submit function? are you sure is entering that if? have you done console.log inside the if?

Comment: @Erubiel yeah I've console.logged the if and it's definitely getting there

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using **vue2-dropzone**

You'll need to set `autoProcessQueue` option to false.

https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-autoProcessQueue

Then you can grab the files before sending with: `this.$refs.myVueDropzone.files`

Where myVueDropzone is the ref you actually provided...

if this doesn't work try with: `this.$refs.myVueDropzone.dropzone.files`

Comment: This prevents the dropzone from uploading the file, and still doesn't allow me to submit the form.